# Downloading a file using VB.net is incomplete

Tags: vb.net

I searched everywhere but without benefit.

I'm using this code to download a file :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
Imports System.Net
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Step4

    Function GetUserName() As String
        If TypeOf My.User.CurrentPrincipal Is 
          System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal Then
            ' The application is using Windows authentication.
            ' The name format is DOMAIN\USERNAME.
            Dim parts() As String = Split(My.User.Name, "\")
            Dim username As String = parts(1)
            Return username
        Else
            ' The application is using custom authentication.
            Return My.User.Name
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Step4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Code of Step3
        Dim URL As String = "http://skinsserver.exampleserver.com/skins.zip"
        Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\" + GetUserName() + "\AppData\Roaming\Applicationsettings\skins.zip"
        Using wc As New WebClient
            wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)")
            wc.DownloadFile(URL, filename)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried everything but only 800 byte of the file is being downloaded while it is 22 KB.

Downloading via browser is fine.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the real URL so we can try ?

Comment: I uploaded the same file on another server and this code worked fine. But this is the server which I must use, any way to fix that?

Comment: The link in your question code isn't working even in the browser.

Comment: @Youssef13 ,  Yes, same here, it not working in the browser.

Comment: No this was an example link. I uploaded the same file on another server and it is working. The link that have the problem is: http://skinsserver.mohtarfcraft.ezyro.com/skins.zip - Can you please help me to get it working on this server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my server, I cannot download the file from this server.
Sorry @Youssef13 - even using a cookie didn't work.

Here is the solution: http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2016/04/13/how-to-upload-and-download-files-with-ftp-from-a-vb-net-application.aspx

I used FTP to download the file.

Comment: Using cookie works for me, Could you explain if you're getting exception or a small file ?

Comment: I get the same filesize (800 bytes).

Comment: I tried the code just now and it works for me perfectly. Could you change the extension of the downloaded file to txt and upload its content ?

Answer (score 1):

The URL you're trying to download from requires a cookie.

Use this:

```
wc.Headers.Add("Cookie", "__test=3c020c18923605cf39e4292d69038f3a")
```

Comment: This worked! But I used another method which is downloading from the FTP server: http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2016/04/13/how-to-upload-and-download-files-with-ftp-from-a-vb-net-application.aspx - No I will download using HTTP. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
"http://skinsserver.exampleserver.com/skins.zip",
"path_where_you_want_to_download")
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/how-to-download-a-file

Comment: I uploaded the same file on another server and this code worked fine. But this is the server which I must use, any way to fix that?

Comment: Both of the methods above should work and do the job. Probably there's a problem with your server's configuration..

Comment: Try with another file so you can see if it's the file's fault or the server's.